# storing values with .nextLine() in array skipping lines

Tags: java, arrays, methods, java.util.scanner

My previous question was closed, but the answer suggested wasn't much help to me. Sorry for the inconvenience.

I'm trying to store `fname`, `lname`, `address`, `city`, `state`, and `zip` in array `customerData[30][6]`. However, it seems to be skipping lines where I'd input the information.

**Code**

```
public void addCustomer() throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numCustomers = 0;
        String[][] customerData = new String[30][7];

        System.out.println("how many customers");
        numCustomers = scan.nextInt();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("/Users/simonshamoon/eclipse-workspace/Final Project/src/customerdata.txt"));

        BufferedWriter loginWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("/Users/simonshamoon/eclipse-workspace/Final Project/src/userlogin.txt"));

        for (int i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++) {

            System.out.println("enter customer data (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip)");

            for (int j = 0; j < customerData[i].length; j++) {
                customerData[i][j] = scan.nextLine();

            }
            writer.write(customerData[i][0] + ", " + customerData[i][1] + ", " + customerData[i][2] + ", "
                    + customerData[i][3] + ", " + customerData[i][4] + ", " + customerData[i][5] + "\n");

            loginWriter.write(customerData[i][0].charAt(0) + customerData[i][1] + ", " + rand.nextInt(10001) + "ASU"
                    + ", Customer" + "\n");

        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        loginWriter.flush();
        loginWriter.close();

    }
```

**Output**

```
how many customers
1
enter customer data (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip)
fname
lname
123 address dr
city
state
zip
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:709)
    at Employee.addCustomer(Employee.java:156)
    at Employee.displayEmployeeMenu(Employee.java:196)
    at BasicMethods.promptUser(BasicMethods.java:48)
    at Shop.main(Shop.java:8)
```

I want it so that `customerData[i][0] = fname`, `customerData[i][1] = lname`, etc etc. I've tried playing around with `.nextLine` and the array sizes, but I believe the problem stems from the space needed in `address`.

Comment: What was the suggested answer?

Comment: it was closed and there was a link to another article about scanner skipping with ```nextLine()```

Comment: what is code at line StringLatin1.java:48?

Comment: @karan that's part of the standard library

Comment: You missed including a few things; `scan` is used but not declared; the inner `for` loop runs until `customerData[i].length`, with `customerData` declared nowhere.
We can guess but that's usually not a good idea. Also, which line is 156?

Comment: @simonshampoo does `writer` write? If yes, what does it write?

Comment: what is code at line Employee.java:156 then?

Comment: @daniu I declared ```scan``` and ```customerData``` in the early lines of the code was they were used in my other  methods. Line 156 is ```loginWriter.write(customerData[i][0].charAt(0) + customerData[i][1] + ", " + rand.nextInt(10001) + "ABC"
     + ", Customer" + "\n");```

Answer (score 0):

So here you create the customer data:

```
for (int j = 0; j < customerData[i].length; j++) {
    customerData[i][j] = scan.nextLine();
}
```

And here is the writer code using `charAt`:

```
loginWriter.write(customerData[i][0].charAt(0) + customerData[i][1] + ", " + rand.nextInt(10001) + "ASU" + ", Customer" + "\n");
```

So it looks like `customerData[i][0]` is an empty String since it's the only use of `charAt` which throws the index exception.

I suggest you either output your individual data items or better yet, step through your code with a debugger.

Since you don't show the surrounding code (how is `scan` created; maybe it's reused but accidentally closed in the meantime?) we can only make reasonable guesses.